# Binary manipulation without file size multiplication

Tags: bit-manipulation

(I believe) when a binary file is made into a format that is capable of being edited, it (the new "editable" text representation) becomes roughly 10x larger than the original file. Now I imagine this is generally not a problem on the whole; however I am curious if there would be a way to edit the binary data without having to deal with this issue; perhaps purely in RAM without creating the rep? And once the binary representation is edited, how do I convert it back to the original format to reduce the size again?

Comment: You might want to start of by naming the language you are working with, and maybe show some code that `edits a binary file`

Comment: You can edit binary files just fine, no conversion is necessary

Comment: This question seems a little broad.  If you are asking if there are editors to edit binary files: yes there are. And they don't convert the file, edit the new file, and then convert back, but convert the binary data in a way readable and editable by the user on the fly.

Comment: Excellent! this is what i assumed. So I assume then that I am just a bit of knowledge away from doing this programmatically? Like counting the iterations of a set of bits or performing arithmetic on the raw binary?

Comment: I am mostly using C,C++,and Labview.

Comment: What are your requirements? Can't you just use an existing editor?

Comment: This question is much too ambiguous. The implication that the file grows ten times implies that we are dealing with compressed data. (binary numbers to text expansion would approximate 2.5x) How can we assess the possibility of seeing data if the compression format is unknown nor the data format?

Comment: @warren: As I understood we are talking about bits here (it's tagged [tag:bit-manipulation]) so each byte becomes 8 characters plus maybe a space to separate bytes.  Add some line endings and an offset into the file at each line start and it's roughly about 10× more bytes in the text file.